# window.opener.document.getElementById(ID of Button).click() results in javascript error in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Google chrome gives this javascript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lnkBtnHidden','') has no method 'click'
```

while executing this line

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_lnkBtnHidden').click();
```

I have verified that the control is in the opener page and that the ID of the button is same as well, but `window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_lnkBtnHidden')` returns this, rather than an object:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lnkBtnHidden','')
```

This happens only in Chrome...

**EDIT:** The code used to open the window is like this:

```
win= window.open('/PageName.aspx?qs=qsValue','','scrollbars=1,width=1000,height=950');
win.moveTo(0,0);
```

Comment: What kind of element(tagName) is the "control"

Comment: This is basically an `anchor` control but I have also tried it with `input type=submit` with same result

Comment: click() doesn't work for anchors in Chrome, but it should work there for input. However, the click-method isn't trustable on any element. Try fireevent(IE) and dispatchEvent(others) instead.

Comment: after changing it to `dispatchEvent('onClick')`, it gives the following error `Uncaught Error: UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events`. I think the issue is because the javascript is not returning an object for `window.opener.document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_lnkBtnHidden')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be confused by the returned

```
    
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$lnkBtnHidden','')
```

some browsers use the href-attribute of an hyperlink as a string-representation of the <a/>-element.
  The returned object still is the element-object.

I already wrote inside the comment that click() in (my) Chrome doesn't work on a-elements. It works for me in `input[type=submit]` , but maybe your chrome-version doesn't support it. But that doesn't matter as long as you can't rely on the fact that click() works anywhere.

When  your approach by using dispatchEvent() doesn't work, I guess your implementation is wrong, here an example-function:

```
//@param obj element where to simulate the click
function simclick(obj)
{

  if(document.fireEvent) {
    obj.fireEvent("onclick"); 

    }
   else if(document.dispatchEvent) { 
    var oEvent = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
    oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true,window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, obj);
    obj.dispatchEvent( oEvent );
    } 
}
```

What else: you should move the call of `javascript:__doPostBack()` from the href-attribute to the onclick-attribute. Otherwise there is no guarantee that the function gets called(depending on the browser).

see an example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/swR59/show/
opener-source: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/swR59/
popup-source: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vHwCr/

Comment: I am accepting your answer, because it is the right solution, but please change the if statement to `if(document.fireEvent)` because Internet Explorer (ver. 9) recognizes both of `fireEvent` and `dispatchEvent`, but do not fire event using `dispatchEvent`, so else would automatically work for chrome...